# Events not called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

Code that does not work:

```
//Add the search textfield
var textField = document.createElement("input");
textField.setAttribute("id" , "textF")
textField.setAttribute("type", "text");
textField.setAttribute("name", "textField");
textField.addEventListener("keypress" , "keyPressedOnTextField(e)");
//textField.setAttribute("onkeypress", "keyPressedOnTextField(e)"); violates policy
document.body.appendChild(textField);

//Add the open in Skroutz Button
var btn = document.createElement("input");
btn.setAttribute("id" , "btn")
btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
btn.setAttribute("value", "Open In Skroutz.gr");
btn.setAttribute("name", "openInSrkoutz");
btn.addEventListener("click" , "openInSkroutzButton()");
//btn.setAttribute("onclick", "openInSkroutzButton()"); violates policy
document.body.appendChild(btn);

function keyPressedOnTextField(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        openInTheWindow();
        return false;
    }
}


function openInSkroutzButton(){
  console.log("test");
  var searchText = getCurrentText();
  console.log(searchText);
  if(searchText === null || searchText < 2){//make sure to replace whitespaces with +
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: "http://www.skroutz.gr/"});
  }else{

    chrome.tabs.create({ url: ("http://www.skroutz.gr/search?keyphrase=" + searchText).replace(/\s/g, "+")});
  }
}

function getCurrentText(){
    return document.getElementById("textField").value;   
}
```

I am trying to add some elements via JS to the document, in a Chrome extension.
The events are not called- although [appears](http://prntscr.com/5lu2u7)

`openInSkroutzButton()` doesn't get called when I click the button

Comment: No one is going to go through all the code on another site to answer a vague question. Post the code that is not working in your question.

Comment: This will get you nowhere. Add some details to the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help] to see how to ask questions here. In particular, questions must be **self-contained** rather than relying on links; links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Be clear about your question: Say what you're trying to do, what you expect to happen, what's happening instead, and why that surprises you. Create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) if at all possible. Once you post your question, *stick around* to respond to comments asking for more information, don't ask-and-run.

Comment: Please add some code and also read [What questions to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what questions to avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

For starters... Remove the quotes from the function name and drop the parentheses. You want to pass a reference to the function (not execute it).

Also, you don't need to explicitly pass the event object to your event handlers... It will be passed automagically.

Change:

```
textField.addEventListener("keypress" , "keyPressedOnTextField(e)");
```

to

```
textField.addEventListener("keypress" , keyPressedOnTextField);
```

and

```
btn.addEventListener("click" , "openInSkroutzButton()");
```

to

```
btn.addEventListener("click", openInSkroutzButton);
```